# "Will be led" explain

Tags: past-tense, future

I am curious about the parts of speech of ...  Class "will be led" by....  Isn't **led** past tense,  while **will** is future tense.  Can anyone explain this to me?  Why is this correct grammar?  (or is it?)

Answer (score 1):

The *led* in

[1] *The class will be led by Kim.*

is used to make a **passive voice** construction. The active voice equivalent would be

[2] *Kim will lead the class.*

So *led* is here not the past tense of *lead*, but rather the past **participle**. While one of the uses of the past participle is to form tenses like the present perfect (*Kim has led the class before*), which are about the past, another use of it is to form the passive voice.

In the case of *lead*, the past tense has the same form as the past participle (*lead/led/led*). But there are verbs for which the two are different, e.g. *choose/chose/chosen*. And it would be *the class will be chosen*, not <sup>*</sup>*the class will be chose*.